# Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined(awesome-typescript-loader)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

I successfully converted my existing angular 2 project into angular 4, but after conversion getting following error :-

- Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of
  undefined

For more details, please refer attached image below

[image]

my **package.json** and **tsconfig.json** file provided below.

**package.json**:-

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "project",
  "keywords": [
    "project"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.44",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.47",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "parse5": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.0",
    "tslint": "~3.15.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.27",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.11",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "selenium-webdriver",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },

  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Comment: Have you get any solution? If yes please answer because it'll help to the other.

Comment: No not yet, but it’s basically versioning issue. The problem will get solve if I convert my typescript version to less than or equal to 2.0 but even after successful compilation project will not running properly because angular 4 required 2.1 or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to awesome-typescript-loader and typescript compatibility issue, you can [check](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/293#issuecomment-314295904)

If you can change the typescript and awesome-typescript-loader version.

Comment: Thank you Shirish.
But I already try to run project with suitable version which is 2.0.10.
I required  typescript version 2.2.2 or higher 
otherwise it will throw to many syntax error and ambiguity error

Comment: I'm sorry I've miss guide you about the issue please check new link

Comment: No problem.
I follow the instruction from specified link but after completing all changes it is giving me following error:-
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin'